# How do I import and use a dll into R

Tags: r, wininet

I am trying to access the methods of `wininet.dll` from within R.

I am able to load the library with

```
dyn.load("C:/Windows/System32/wininet.dll")
```

And I can see that it is loaded for example:

```
is.loaded('InternetOpenA')
```

returns the value `TRUE`.

However, if I try to use the method e.g. like so:

```
.Call('InternetOpenA', "Mozilla/4.1337",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,NULL,NULL, 0)
```

I get the error:

```
Error: object 'INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG' not found
```

And if I do

```
.Call('InternetOpenA', "Mozilla/4.1337",'INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG',NULL,NULL, 0)
```

My RStudio R Session stops working:

[image: Like so]

I started doing this because I wanted to understand better the way that the function `download.file()`  operates in R. From it's own description, it relies on `wininet` when the OS is Windows and the requests are http. I understand that one can better use `curl`, `httr` or `download.file()` to download files, but my end goal is to understand how I should pass the parameters to a function loaded via a dll.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of `dll` are you talking about? Usually, R can make use of `dll`s which deal with R objects and the `.Call` interface expects a `SEXP` object to be returned by the called function (and the argument are `SEXP` objects as well). It's unlikely that you can use an arbitrary `dll` from R.

Comment: Thanks. the `dll` I want to use is `wininet.dll`, which is used by `download.file()` so shouldn't be _too_ arbitrary.  I'll start finding out about SEXP objects.

Comment: Maybe you want the `.C` interface to the C language? See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran) and `help("Foreign")`.

Comment: @ColBates-collynomial As far as I can tell, `wininet` is not used directly by `download.file`; rather there is likely a wrapper that makes use of it. The rule is this: you can load any `dll`, but with the `.Call` interface you can call only a function that expects `SEXP` objects (the C type of a R object) and returns a `SEXP`/R object. Very likely your  `wininet` function will return something that cannot be easily interpreted as an R object.

Comment: Values like `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG` are usually variables defined in source code and are replaces with numeric values when you compile. Looking [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet.internetopen), `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG` corresponds to a value of 0. You'd have to use the numeric value when invoking via `.Call`

Comment: Other random points: be careful that something like `0` in R is `double`; so if the argument of the called C function is integer, you should use `0L`. Also, `NULL` in R and `NULL` in `C` are rather different things.

Comment: `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG` is actually an integer (see https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/mingw/include/wininet.h#L75); what happens if you pass `0L` instead of a string for that 3rd argument?

Comment: @RichieCotton Nothing good is going to happen (the code is reproducible on a windows pc or through wine). Even a single string is very different from R to C. No way this is going to work. Very likely there is another way to accomplish what OP is looking for.

Comment: @RichieCotton I tried this, @nicola is correct: I kill the R session. I'm going to do as is hinted at above by @nicola and try build a wrapper function which calls `wininet`. This has been a real good learning experience. I will submit an answer ... if I get there.